# Get and Set custom attribute of li tag onClick dynamically using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JavaScript.I have the following requirement.

I need to get the custom attribute(data-counter) of my li tag, do certain manipulation and later set it (data-counter) back with some value on each click of the **particular** li tag dynamically using javascript.

Example

```html
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="5" onclick="capture(this);">A</li>
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="4" onclick="capture(this);">B</li>
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="1" onclick="capture(this);">C</li>
```

Onclick of my B li tag. It should look like below

```html
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="5" onclick="capture(this);">A</li>
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="1" data-value="4" onclick="capture(this);">B</li>
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="1" onclick="capture(this);">C</li>
```

where my data-counter value of B li tag has alone changed to value "1".

How do I accomplish this Using Javascript? I have tried quite a few solution's on net but none of them have worked for me.

Please, Kindly provide me the possible solutions.

Thank you in advance

Comment: ID should be unique

Comment: show us your JS.. like to see what you've tried

Comment: what if i remove id attribute from my li tags.How can I get to my solution?

Comment: Muthu Kumaran 

Below is My JS

<script type="text/javascript">

        function capture(d){
            var a=d.getAttribute("data-value");
            if (a.equals("0"))
   {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-value]').setAttribute("data-value", "1");
    
   }
   else
   {
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-value]').setAttribute("data-value", "0");
   }
        }

</script>

Answer (score 2):

Remove duplicate ID. ID's must be unique for each elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

As you are passing the clicked element's reference, you could just use `dataset` to update the counter.

```js
function capture(e){
  e.dataset.counter++;
  console.log(e.dataset.counter);
}
```

```html
<li  class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="5" onclick="capture(this);">A</li>
<li  class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="4" onclick="capture(this);">B</li>
<li  class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="1" onclick="capture(this);">C</li>
```

You can learn more about `dataset` from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `attr` to fetch the current `data-counter` and keep incrementing it, and set it again using `attr()`:

```js
function capture(element) {
  $(element).attr('data-counter', parseInt($(element).attr('data-counter')) + 1);
  console.log('New data-counter value is: ' + $(element).attr('data-counter'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="5" onclick="capture(this);">A</li>
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="4" onclick="capture(this);">B</li>
<li id="myInput" class="question" data-counter="0" data-value="1" onclick="capture(this);">C</li>
```